# как подставить значения из базы данных?

Tags: php, python, sql, sqlite

нужно получить с таблицы Group строку с данными и подменить их например 
[3]-[2]
первое значения в квадратных скобках значит что нужно взять с таблицы List 3 строку с данными 'трактор' и другое значение с таблицы Brand 'джон дип'
и эти значение поместить в две разные переменные

трактор - джон дип

```
List
    |---------|----------| 
    | list_id |  title   |
    |---------|----------|
    |    1    |  машина  |
    |---------|----------|
    |    2    | мотоцикл |
    |---------|----------|
    |    3    | трактор  |
    |---------|----------|

Brand
    |---------|----------| 
    |brand_id |  title   |
    |---------|----------|
    |    1    |  ауди    |
    |---------|----------|
    |    2    | джон дир |
    |---------|----------|
    |    3    |  дукати  |
    |---------|----------|


Group
    |----------|-------------------| 
    | Group_id |       text        |
    |----------|-------------------|
    |    1     | [4]-[23],         |
    |          | [9]-[3]           |
    |----------|-------------------|
    |    2     | [2]-[37],         |
    |          | [8]-[41],         |
    |          | [11]-[24],        |
    |          | [2]-[15]          |
    |----------|-------------------|
```

Comment: Не создавайте новые вопросы, исправте старый

Comment: Не знаю конечно, как у вас создаётся таблица `Group`,но может быть легче в таблицу `Brand` добавить ещё одну колонку-связь с таблицей `List`, а в таблице `Group` хранить лишь `list_id` через запятую? Например таблица `Brand` - `brand_id | title | list_id`. Тогда можно будет выводить все "машины" к примеру, `list_id` которых мы находим в таблице `Brand`. Например text в таблице `Group` - `2,8,11`. В конце концов от таблицы `Group` вообще можно избавиться.